# PHP, MYSQL and hyperlinks - linking from one page to a detail page (same table)

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

Not sure why this page doesn't seem to be working?

Trying to get the ID from the URL and use that to filter a table.

Example URL: http://example.com/page.php?id=123G

I'm getting 0 results when I type in that URL even though I know there is a match.  Any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;}</style>
</head>

<?php

$id = $_GET["id"];

$servername = "INSERTSERVER";
$username = "INSERTUSER";
$password = "INSERTPASSWORD";
$dbname = "INSERTDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$pd = "

SELECT fac_id, pd, phone_pd 
FROM ft_location_db
WHERE fac_id = $id

";


$result = $conn->query($pd);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table cellpadding=5 bgcolor=#FFFFFF><tr><th>PD</th><th>Phone</th>
</tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["pd"]. "</td><td>" . $row["phone_pd"]. "</td>
</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}






$conn->close();
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the identifier is `123G`, `fac_id` column seems to be a string datatype, right?

Comment: Yep is there a problem with that? It is unique.

Comment: Actually figured this out.  WHERE fac_id = $id needed to be WHERE fac_id = '$id'    Very new to SQL and PHP.  What is the deal with ' and "? Seems like I see things written different ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, see the note in the bottom of the answer.

If `fac_id` is a string datatype, it should be wrapped.

```
$pd = "
SELECT fac_id, pd, phone_pd 
FROM ft_location_db
WHERE fac_id = '$id'
";
```

You have to use single quotes, because your query is written inside double quotes.

Using single quotes :

```
$pd = '
SELECT fac_id, pd, phone_pd 
FROM ft_location_db
WHERE fac_id = "' . $id . '"
';
```

**But (and -very- important)**, I suggest you to take a look to [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to secure your queries.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('
    SELECT fac_id, pd, phone_pd 
    FROM ft_location_db
    WHERE fac_id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

See also : [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: *"Because variable are not interpreted inside single quotes strings."* - Huh?

Comment: you sort of had it right, but what I said above in quoting you, needs to be edited or deleted.

Comment: Is this vulnerable to sql injection? I thought being a prepared statement I was okay?? Thanks!

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I've removed this sentence. It's probably a mistake about my translation. But I don't what was my error here. Can you enlighten me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Talsma Yes, it is vulnerable. Use prepared statements, as soon as possible :)

Comment: @Syscall it might have just been a language barrier; no worries.

Comment: @Syscall Can you provide an example using above code using MySQLi and prepared statements?  Would really appreciate it!!

Comment: @Talsma You have some examples in the given link. I've updated the anwser to use your context (not tested).